# Visa/permit for foreign tourists to visit the Andaman Islands?

Tags: visas, india, andaman-nicobar-islands

As I've learnt from the [What are “prohibited / restricted areas” in the context of an Indian visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43582/26) question, a normal tourist visa issued to a foreigner isn't valid for much (all?) of the Andaman islands.

Inspired in part by [this question on Diving in the Andamans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6085/26), I'm considering trying to work a side trip over there to do some scuba diving on a future trip to India. However, I now discover that my current visa wouldn't cover that.

So, as a foreigner in possession of an Indian visa marked "Not Valid for Prohibited / Restricted and Cantonment areas", how do I go about getting permission / extra visa / permit to visit the Andaman islands?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just need an additional permit (same [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/protected-restricted-area-permit-india.html) source):

Permit Granting Authorities:
MHA & FRROS
All Indian Missions abroad
Chief Immigration Officer, Chennai
Immigration Officer, Port Blair

Remarks:
If arriving by air, permission to stay up to 30 days is issued on arrival at the airport in Port Blair.
If arriving by sea, permit is needed in advance, as it is required to buy the ticket.

Places from 1 to 8, day and night visit allowed.
Places from 14 to 24, only day visit allowed.
Night stay in 9 is subject to special permission of the U.T. Administration.
Individual tourists are permitted, 30 days allowed.