# Air Travel to the Andamans

Tags: air-travel, india, andaman-nicobar-islands

In reference to this question: [Visa/permit for foreign tourists to visit the Andaman Islands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43620/visa-permit-for-foreign-tourists-to-visit-the-andaman-islands)

It is said that foreigners visiting the Andamans by air may apply for the appropriate PAP upon arrival at the airport in Port Blair.

If flying international and arriving, say, in Kolkata, is it advisable to have already booked the complete flight itinerary to Port Blair, or is it recommended to book the Port Blair flight upon arrival in Kolkata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [website](http://www.andamans.gov.in/html/entryformality.html) of the Andaman and Nicobar government, you will be able to receive the Restricted Area Permit on arrival at Port Blair Airport. The website also mentions that you'll be able to apply for the permit at all Indian missions abroad.

While I would assume that you will be able to board your flight to Port Blair from Kolkata without any problems, if you really wish to have this itinerary foolproof and account for checking staff error, you may consider applying for the permit at an Indian mission before arriving in India. Whether you have flights to Port Blair on one itinerary or separate ones does not matter in either the case of applying before or recieving it on arrival.